# sql: an alias was previously found (near No)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables, one for questions and another for choices for those questions. I am trying to execute an sql query that would let me see the questions along with the choices however whenever i execute the following sql query it shows me the error I mentioned on the title of this question.

here is my sql query

```
SELECT 
  questions.Question,choices.Choice 
FROM `questions` 
INNER JOIN choices.QuestionNo=questions.No;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FROM` is malformed -- no `ON` clause and no reference to `choices`.

I think you intend:

```
SELECT questions.Question, choices.Choice
FROM questions INNER JOIN
     choices
     ON choices.QuestionNo = questions.No;
```

I would recommend using table aliases for this:

```
SELECT q.Question, c.Choice
FROM questions q INNER JOIN
     choices c
     ON c.QuestionNo = q.No;
```